# Not able to navigate to a different View Controller from AlertViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a UIALertViewController setup which shows me an alert:

```
     let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rate me", message: "Thanks!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rate it Now", style: .Default, handler: { alertAction in
        self.defaults.removeObjectForKey("count")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remind Me Later", style: .Default, handler: { alertAction in
        self.defaults.removeObjectForKey("count")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No, Thanks", style: .Default, handler: { alertAction in

        print("hello")
        let controller = WebViewController(nibName: "WebViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

    }))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

What I want is when I click the third button(No thanks button), I want to go to different view controller. But it seems to be not working for some reason. It prints hello to the console but does not go to the view controller. This should be pretty straightforward but I am not able to figure out what's wrong. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your `navigationController` nil?

Comment: Or your WebViewController?

Comment: no, none of them is nil.

Comment: I tried going to WebViewController from another view controller and it worked, so WebViewController is not nil. What's the best way to check whether navigation controller controller is nil or not?

Comment: Wrap your `navigationController` access in a check just to make sure `if let nav = self.navigationController { nav.pushViewController...... } else { print("nav is nil") }`

Comment: yes you are right, navigation controller is nil, how can I add this view controller to navigation stack?

Comment: Is the current viewcontroller on a nav stack? Did you get here via pushViewController or presentViewController or did you use a segue?

Comment: The current view controller is on the nav stack, I got here via pushViewController.